# How to draw an arc between two angles?

Tags: unity, geometry

I'd like to draw an arc between two specific angles. For example, "draw an angle between 0 and 90 degrees" and it will draw only that part of the circle and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an arc with a radius and start and end angle. Then you simply need to create a series of points to define the arc.

```
List<Vector2> arcPoints = new List<Vector2>();
float angle = startAngle;
float arcLength = endAngle - startAngle;
for (int i = 0; i <= segments; i++)
{
    float x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * radius;
    float y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * radius;

    arcPoints.Add(new Vector2(x,y));

    angle += (arcLength / segments);
}
```

This example creates a list of points that define an arc. The arc can be made "smoother" by increasing the number of segments.

Drawing the arc is your choice, you can create a [mesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html), use the [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) or something like [GL.LINES](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this algorithme achieve something like this : http://bit.ly/2aZBvwk Or I will get a pizza-like shape ? (for reference I want to do something like the image)

Comment: This algorithm simply defines the points that make up the arc. It's up to you to decide how to render them. The LineRenderer would probably be the easiest option for what you want. Just set the LineRenderer's points to the ones generated in the algorithm above.

Comment: Thansk for your help.

Comment: Mind if i ask another question ? :What I want to to draw these line relatively to my transform ?

Comment: Add the position of the transform to each of the arc points.

Comment: That doesnt work for an unknown reason :(, if i leave `x,y` it draws at position 0 of the world, If I add the transform position, it doesnt draw anything, (or it draws behing my sprites ?)

Comment: You can also make the line renderer a child of the gameobject, and make sure it's not using world coordinates (a check box on the line renderer)